# 'Quick shredding' home directory encrypted with ecryptfs

Tags: linux, security, encryption, ecryptfs

I need to re-use a disk from another computer and would like to ensure existing data can be as hard to recover as possible, without making full shred runs over the entire device (when drives are, say, 4Tb+ in size, shredding can take quite a time).

Is there a way to quickly render ecryptfs-encrypted home directory indecipherable?

Examples:

a. If I need to 'quick shred' a Veracrypt-encrypted device, all I need to do is to shred first 2<sup>17</sup> bytes, which will destroy volume header and the master key therein.

b. If I need to 'quick shred' encfs-encrypted directory (provided it's not on journaling filesystem), shredding corresponding .encfs*.xml file might be sufficient.

Is there similar 'quick shred' procedure for ecryptfs-encrypted directories?

Comment: It's not exactly quick, but if you're just wiping the device for internal reuse, then just zeroing out the contents of the partition and wiping the key from all locations it's stored is sufficient unless you are worried about some government seeing the data.  Recovering the ciphertext in such a situation requires funding that's beyond almost anyone but governments (either to procure and use an atomic force microscope, or to in some way obtain enough info about SSD firmware to find the data).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Thanks for comment. One-pass zeroing is somewhat faster than filling with pseudo-random data, but it still takes hours. Yes, I do not target government-scale adversary (in which case the only reliable way is physical reliable irreversible destruction of the entire computer and all the devices used to store key(s)).  

Since each ecryptfs-encrypted file is self-sufficient (doesn't rely on a central keystore, like in encfs), the 'quick shred' options I thought of are a) irreversibly overwriting the directories within encrypted hierarchy; b) partially overwriting files.

Comment: Provided you're not using a copy-on-write filesystem (BTRFS, ZFS, NILFS2, etc) as the backing storage, just zeroing out each individual file and overwriting the directories should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eCryptfs keeps it's actual mount passphrase in the file

```
/home/.ecryptfs/user/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

So just shredding that file would work. Then even with the user's password you'd have to do a brute force attack to recover the files.